# concatenation error between strings within a list

Tags: python, string, list, string-concatenation

I am trying to create an interval timer but have ran into the problem that the lists will not hold strings in my case, only single letters and single numbers. Interval_name can be any string but the list will break it up into single characters. Interval_time can be any integer but does the same thing. Interval_type is uneeded for this function

```
def create_interval():
    global setnum
    global intarray
    global strarray

    interval_type = interval_type_var.get()
    interval_name = interval_name_entry.get()
    interval_time = str(interval_time_entry.get())
    print(interval_name, interval_type, interval_time)
    if interval_name and interval_type:
         setnum = setnum + 1
         array_listbox.insert(END, (setnum,":", str(interval_name)), int((interval_time)),(interval_type))
         nextarva = (interval_time)
         intarray.append(nextarva)
         nextstr = (interval_name)
         strarray.append(nextstr)
         intarray = "".join(intarray)
         strarray = "".join(strarray)
         print(intarray)
         print(strarray)
```

I have tried using the + operation but it just gives me the same errors, if I am doing it wrong Im clearly not sure how to use it. Is this a common problem or is it just me?
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"
is the error when .append is used
"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"
is the errors when + opperation is used

Comment: What error are you facing? Maybe this will help `array = "".join(str(elem) for elem in array)`

Comment: this returns an error the same error as before being: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: On which lines do the errors occur? Please add the full traceback. I guess that one of `intarray` and `strarray` is a `list` and the other a `str`, but I can't know.

Comment: Yes the error occurs from intarray and strarray

Comment: `intarray` and `strarray` are global variables. So at the end of the function when you do `intarray = "".join(intarray)` and `strarray = "".join(strarray)`, you make them into strings, and so the next time your function is called, they're strings and not lists.